# Can cycling improve my stamina in soccer?

Tags: exercise, cross-training

I cycle about 2 km uphill every day, and it takes me about 16 minutes on my MTB.

I hope this will also improve my stamina in soccer as I am unable to sprint/run fast.

Please suggest me some good diet.  I am allergic to eggs.

I am 20 years  male  and I weigh 74kg ,height 5.6 ft. Is my body weight OK or bad?

[image]

Comment: Cycling can improve your running performance up to a certain point. 16 minutes per day is very little, that’s barely long enough for a warm-up. The good/healthy range for body weight depends on how tall you are. BMI is a good first approximation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a question about bicycles.  Might be a better fit for https://fitness.stackexchange.com/ but even then would need some refinements to the question which is far too broad

Comment: @AndyP yeah - I'd migrate it but first half of the question would be off topic over there.

Comment: Just an observation: that seems to be a single speed bike; climbing with low cadence, on a high gear, may be a different kind of training than climbing with high cadence on a low gear (different muscle fibers involved, different heart rates, different position and technique, etc)

Comment: Am I missing something here? OP is half my age, weighs 6kg less and is around the same height give or take a few mm. You are borderline overweight, your current BMI would be around 26 based on what we know, I’d say average body shape. OP is young and should have no trouble training to run, however you can’t train for running while being on a bike. OP needs to do at least some running training.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to run fast, you need somewhat structured training. Normal bicycle commuting is certainly beneficial to ones health, but without structuring it it will be often too short fort endurance training or too slow for speed training. If you want to be fast (on the bike, but there is some limited overlap) you need to train shorter fast sections - like sprints and short time trials. If you want to have endurance for long activities, you need to train long rides. Those can be your commutes, but you would have to significantly extend it.

The overlap to running is there but is not perfect, the sports use different muscles to some extent (as I reminded myself painfully when returning to running very recently), but at least you use the same lungs and the same heart - but also many common muscles.  You will certainly also need to train running specifically and the same logic applies. Short fast intervals for speed, long runs for endurance, but there are many detailed advices on running-specific sites.

Discussing your diet is really a completely different topic and cannot be done here. Look elsewhere, but normal healthy diet with balanced income of basic nutrients should be the start.

Comment: Although climbs might improve lung capacity 16 minutes is a bit on the short side.

Comment: @Carel Might be okay for one rep in a set of 3-5 intervals

Answer (score 6):

Cycling 2 km in 16 minutes is about 8 km/h which could be fast or slow depending on the gradient.

No this won't do a lot for your running sprint, because climbing is about endurance, and running sprints is about peak power.

Diets are really personal, and well outside the scope of this site.

Age and weight really aren't comparable.  Height and weight are often related, but there are many more variables that go into it, and this is not on-topic for bicycles.

Your second two questions might get better answers on https://fitness.stackexchange.com/ but we can't migrate half of the question.